# Using .rcp files with OneDrive on demand

Tags: onedrive

Why are files saved by Autodesk Recap with extension .rcp not available in OneDrive on demand?

Is it possible to configure it to manage them like all the other documents?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received an answer from my IT: it was explicitly blocked on our SharePoint configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[image] icon means that you have a sync issue.

To see what causing the sync issue, click on the blue cloud button in your tray:

[image]

Most likely, the sync issue occured because one of the following:

- multiple individuals currently work with the same file.
- there was a file merge conflict and it needs to be resolved.

Unlike MS Office documents, **OneDrive for Business sync tool** does not know how to properly merge Autocad files. Might be also because Autocad does not support multiple people working with the same project.

Comment: The sync issue happens because the file extension is .rcp. I have uploaded many folder in the process of migrating from network drive storage to SharePoint, and all the .rcp files are not synced.